# Continuity/Handoff Issue

Tags: ios, continuity

I upgraded my iPhone 5S and my iPad (Model #MC769LL/A) to the iOS 8 operating system.  Both are on the the same WiFi network. Bluetooth is on on both devices.  The iPhone Handoff app setting is on, but not found in iPad settings.  I am able to answer phone call on iPad and use iPad to make a call via the phone.  However, I cannot handoff from one device to another when using Pages, Mail, Numbers, etc.  There is no activity app icon in the lower left corner of the locked screen on either device.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the two devices are connected via wifi and bluetooth. If Bluetooth has lost the link, go into settings and find the other device, touch 'connect'. Check both ways. 
I am not sure if handoff will work on your iPad. At least update to the latest systems. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From googling it looks like iPad model MC769LL/A is an iPad 2nd generation, which unfortunately does not support Handoff nor AirDrop.